# Clarification about Firewall Forwarding

Tags: firewall

If a firewall forwards packets between different networks (internal) and no NAT is used, is there something in the packet where I can see if it was forwarded by a firewall?

Comment: If by firewall you mean `iptables` or so, the rule(s) of it doesn't forward packet. Forwarding by definition means route traffics out when the destination (and source) is not the host itself. In Linux you enable it with sysctl. Firewall rules are optional (by default all forwarding are allowed).

Comment: It does not look like [TCP packets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) contain this information, but what do you want to find out in the end?

Answer (score 0):

This answer only applies if your firewall is `iptables`:

`iptables` has tables named `PREROUTING` and `POSTROUTING`. If you want to watch what packets are passed through these tables, you can use the `LOG` target, for example, like this

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j LOG
```

to log all traffic before being routed. Feel free to add restrictions to commands like this using the usual `iptables` syntax.